# Fourier transform of $\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}$

Tags: maple, fourier-transform

If I try to compute the fourier transform of 
$$
f(x)=\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}
$$
Maple return the function

$$
g(\omega) = \frac{1}{2} \pi e^{-|\omega|}
$$

However when I try to compute the inverse fourier transform of $g$ I get

$$
h(x) = \frac{1}{2(x^2 + 1)}.
$$

command I used are "fourier" and "invfourier". I was wondering if there's a way to derive by "hand" the fourier transform, the function is in $L^2$ so it exists.

Update:

Below a screenshot of the commands I used.

[image]

Comment: Mathematica returns -Sqrt[Pi/2] ExpIntegralEi[-Abs[w]], maybe that's the source of your confusion.

Comment: Maple's answer is definitely wrong, but at the same time it is difficult to accept that such a well-known software product could make such a serious mistake. Indeed, $g$ is the Fourier transform of $h$, not of $f$. Could you please show us your Maple code? (As others have said, the Fourier transform that you are looking for is not expressible by elementary functions.)

Comment: @AlexM. Please, see my update.

Comment: @user8469759: If I were you, I would submit this as a bug report to the Maple team. Doing this would help many other users. You, at least, used a simple code that allowed you to spot the bug, but what about those large Maple projects that contain calls to `fourier` deep in their code? So, why not be an ethical user and file a bug report, containing precisely the above code and its output? But before this: with your notations above, what is the output of `fourier(g,w,t)` and of `fourier(1/(x^2+1),x,t)`?

Comment: @AlexM. I would like to follow up on this discussion since the OP has abandoned it. I have both MMA and Maple (latest versions) and retried the above sequence, the values are same as what OP has posted (Maple) which is wrong as per this page. I tried it on MMA and the answer matches as per Santiagos post above. I am letting Maple know about this and will get back with any updates.

Comment: @AlexM. Maple discussion: https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/223402-Fourier-Transform-Of-Arctanxx?reply=reply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write

$$\frac{\arctan{x}}{x} = \int_0^1 \frac{du}{1+x^2 u^2} $$

so that the FT may be written as

$$\int_0^1 \frac{du}{u^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{i k x}}{\frac1{u^2}+x^2} $$

The inner integral is simply the FT of the Lorentzian function, or $\pi u e^{-|k|/u}$.  The FT is then

$$\pi \int_0^1 \frac{du}{u} e^{-|k|/u} = \pi \int_1^{\infty} \frac{du}{u} e^{-|k| u} = \pi \Gamma(0,|k|)$$

Comment: I'm confused now, is the fourier transform maple provided me correct?

Comment: @user8469759: no.

Comment: ok, i'll try what you said then.

Comment: I don't know... xD, but I've written the function I said.

Comment: Sorry what's the $\Gamma$ in your final expression?

Comment: @user8469759: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition

Comment: Out of curiuosity is it possible to compute the fourier of the gamma function?

Comment: @user8469759: In principle, yes.

Comment: +1. That was the approach I was thinking about it. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

> **Herein, we will use the form of the Fourier Transform of a function $f$ given by $$\mathscr{F}\left(f\right)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{i\omega x}\,dx$$Integrals are interpreted in terms of [Cauchy Principal Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).**

---

We can use the [Convolution Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) to find the Fourier Transform of $\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}$.  First, we note that the Fourier Transforms of $\frac1x$ and $\arctan(x)$ are given respectively by

$$\mathscr{F}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=i\pi \,\text{sgn}(\omega) \tag 1$$

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\left(\arctan(x)\right)&=\frac{i}{\omega}\,\mathscr{F}\left(\frac{d\arctan(x)}{dx}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{i}{\omega}\,\mathscr{F}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{i\,\pi}{\omega} \,e^{-|\omega|} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Then, using the Convolution Theorem, we find that for $\omega\ne 0$, the Fourier Transform of $\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}$ is given by

$$\begin{align}\mathscr{F}\left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\right)&=\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty i\pi \,\text{sgn}(\omega-\omega')\,\frac{i\pi}{\omega'} \,e^{-|\omega'|}\,d\omega'\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\,\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}\text{sgn}(\omega-\omega')\,\frac{e^{-|\omega'|}}{\omega'} \,d\omega'+\int_{\epsilon}^\infty \text{sgn}(\omega-\omega')\,\frac{e^{-|\omega'|}}{\omega'}\,d\omega'\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\,\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-|\omega|}\text{sgn}(\omega-\omega')\,\frac{e^{-|\omega'|}}{\omega'} \,d\omega'+\int_{|\omega|}^\infty \text{sgn}(\omega-\omega')\,\frac{e^{-|\omega'|}}{\omega'}\,d\omega'\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\left(-\int_{-\infty}^{-|\omega|}\frac{e^{\omega'}}{\omega'} \,d\omega'+\int_{|\omega|}^\infty \,\frac{e^{-\omega'}}{\omega'}\,d\omega'\right)\\\\
&=\pi \int_{|\omega|}^\infty \frac{e^{-\omega'}}{\omega'}\,d\omega'\\\\
&=\pi \Gamma\left(0,|\omega|\right)
\end{align}$$

where $\Gamma(x,y)=\int_y^\infty u^{x-1}e^{-u}\,du$ is the upper [Incomplete Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition).